# is it possible to run ruby commandline tool irb in android device?

Tags: ruby

I am learning ruby

I remember using python commandline tool in android device.. 
Now I want to run code and practice whenever i am free, so I want to run ruby commands in android mobile phone is it possible? 
can I get the irb in my android phone

if it is posible please give me a detailed instruction. I searched online but I don't understand anything

Comment: There's also Ruboto IRB, but it's only v1.9.3 and aspects of its use are confusion. In general, I find running Ruby under Android to be a very poor use of my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download **[Pocket Ruby](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arahaman.pocketruby&hl=en)** app from google play store in your android device. You can write ruby code and run, play with ruby in your mobile.

> Pocket Ruby is used to eval ruby code. Ruby programmers can play with
>   ruby code with this app. User can test Ruby commands just by placing
>   in the text field and clicking on run button. It works similar to Ruby
>   IRB.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use: [ruby repl console](https://repl.it/languages/ruby)

Answer (score 0):

I use irb on Termux: the android shell emulator. The updated version of Termux is in [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org)

If not already installed is done by

`pkg update`
`pkg install ruby`

irb on Termux has ruby IDE specific colors and autocomplete function.